# How to delete a line of text in C++ using regex

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to define a method that deletes an entire line in a block of text containing a string passed to it.

```
#include <regex>

void removePlaceholder(std::string& element, const std::string& placeholder)
{
    std::regex placeholderLine("\n.*" + placeholder);
    std::regex_replace(element, placeholderLine, "");
}
```

This however does not make any changes. What am I missing here?

Sample input:

```
line1
#placeholder
line3
```

Sample output:

```
line1
line3
```

Comment: Can you provide a samle of input and wanted output ?

Comment: @thibsc Included it in the original post.

Comment: You want `element = std::regex_replace(element ...`.

Comment: Also, your regex is incorrect. Try `"\n.*" + placeholder + ".*"`

Comment: @BennyK that regex would match from the start of the line to the end of the string

Comment: @BennyK That's it, thanks. I've been banging my head for two days over this. It never occurred to me that I need to actually use the return value. As for the regex, I use a single string for a placeholder (e.g. #STRING), so there won't be anything after it. Thanks again.

Comment: @StevoIlišković if `placeholder` is the entire string you also don't need the `.*`

Comment: @Benny K There may be some tabs or spaces in front

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regex_replace` returns the modified string, it doesn't modify the passed in string in place.

I presume you also want to add a newline at the end of your regex too so that it matches the whole line rather than stopping at the end of `placeholder`.

You should probably also make the `*` non greedy to prevent matching more than one line by adding `?`

```
void removePlaceholder(std::string& element, const std::string& placeholder)
{
    std::regex placeholderLine("\n.*?" + placeholder + ".*?\n?");
    element = std::regex_replace(element, placeholderLine, "\n");
}
```

A simpler approach might be to replace `.` with a non-newline class:

```
void removePlaceholder(std::string& element, const std::string& placeholder)
{
    std::regex placeholderLine("\n[^\n]*" + placeholder + "[^\n]*");
    element = std::regex_replace(element, placeholderLine, "\n");
}
```

Note that this won't work correctly if placeholder contains any special regex characters, if it does you'll need to escape them.